# Cannot determine from description if selected internal PCI sound card would fit inside a Small Form Factor PC

Tags: usb, windows, mini-pc, audio-adapters, sound-cards

The internal default speaker works but no signal for sound jacks for external amplified speakers. I wish to try two possible solutions.

**Solutions**

1a. check if this already ordered [internal PCI sound card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09RZP13DR) would work and fit with my equipment.

1b. if 1a is wrong is there one that might fit and work? (prefer under $25 at Amazon)

2. is there a USB sound card that might work with my equipment? (prefer under $20 at Amazon)

*Note: prices not firm.*

**Operating System and Equipment**

Windows 10

[HP Compaq 8200 Elite Small Form Factor](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-8200-elite-small-form-factor-pc/5037931)

[Logitech Z533 120W 2-Speaker Stereo with Subwoofer](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/speakers/z533-multimedia-speaker-system.980-001053.html)

[ARTIX CL750 Adult & Kids Wired Headphones with Mic (alternate output)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087JVV8FK)

I look forward to your answers.